Why for a concave and increasing function $f(x)$ we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f' (x)< \infty$
I need to prove that for a concave, increasing and twice differentiable function $f(x)$ we have
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)< \infty \tag{1}$$
I started from this by writing
$$ f(x) \leq f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x-x_0) \Leftrightarrow f'(x) \leq f'(x_0) \tag{2}$$ where the second inequality is obtained by differentiating the first w.r.t. $x$. This implies that $f'(x)$ is upper bounded. Can we say that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) \leq f'(x_0)$ which implies $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) < \infty$ ? Is that a correct approach or there are more accurate approaches to prove (1)?

You cannot just “differentiate inequalities” – $f(x) \le g(x)$ does not imply $f'(x) \le g'(x)$.

It is correct, however, that $f'$ is (weakly) decreasing for a concave function.

@MartinR thank you for the comments. What do you mean by saying $f(x) \le g(x)$ does not imply $f'(x) \le g'(x)$ ? Does this mean that we can't write (2) as stated? If possible, could you provide more details to help enhance the precision of the proof?

We cannot. Take $g$ to be constant and $f$ increasing but below $g.$ Do the derivatives satisfy that inequality?

Your derivation of $(2)$ is wrong because an inequality can not simply be differentiated. (Example: $f(x) = \sin(x) \le g(x) = 1$ does not imply $f'(x) = \cos(x) \le g'(x) = 0$.)
It is correct however, that the derivative of a concave function is decreasing (in the weak sense). For twice differentiable concave functions this follows immediately from $f''(x) \le 0$, but it is true even if the second derivative does not exist, see for example $f(x)$ is convex $\Leftrightarrow f'$ is monotonically increasing.
If $f$ is concave and increasing then $f'$ is (weakly) decreasing and bounded below by zero, and that implies that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists as a finite real value.

Thank you for the answer. Interesting information especially the link! So, as far I understand, we can respectively prove $f(x)$ is concave $\Leftrightarrow f'$ non-increasing and use the fact $f' (x) \geq 0$ to get your final point.

@Thoth: Yes, exactly.
